# When I run `npm i <package>`, sometimes it doesn't install latest version. Is it because of other packages?

Tags: npm, redux, npm-install, package.json, redux-persist

In my React Native project I have the following packages:

```
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-persist": "^4.10.2",
"redux-persist-filesystem-storage": "^2.2.0",
```

I want to upgrade `redux-persist` to the latest version (`6.0.0`), so I ran `npm i redux-persist`, but the version in my `package.json` stayed the same.

Why would this be? Is it because of the versions of the other packages?

Comment: Try `npm install redux-persist@6.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

You can try specifying the version you want to install, like  `npm install redux-persist@<version>`